# Raspberry PI controllable car (code for a 6-year old)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to show my 6-year old daughter a way to build and create a simple toy car. We've got a 4-motor chassis kit, Raspberry PI and a motozero shield that can operate these 4 motors. We've put a power bank and a separate battery for the motors:

[image]

<sub>(The green light on the right is the traffic light)</sub>

Now, as far as coding goes, I've created a simple `Car` class with `forward`, `backward`, `forward_left`, `forward_right`, `backward_left` and `backward_right` actions. For the demonstration purposes mostly, I've tried to be explicit and violated the DRY principle a lot.

I've also initialized an endless loop listening for keyboard inputs - <kbd>F</kbd> would be for forward, <kbd>B</kbd> for backwards and <kbd>S</kbd> for stop (have not decided which keys would go for those "left-ish" and "right-ish" actions yet).

```
from RPi import GPIO
from gpiozero import Motor, OutputDevice


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front_right = Motor(forward=24, backward=27)
        self.front_left = Motor(forward=6, backward=22)

        self.rear_right = Motor(forward=13, backward=18)
        self.rear_left = Motor(forward=23, backward=16)

        OutputDevice(5).on()
        OutputDevice(17).on()
        OutputDevice(25).on()
        OutputDevice(12).on()

    def forward(self):
        self.front_right.forward()
        self.front_left.backward()

        self.rear_right.backward()
        self.rear_left.backward()

    def backward(self):
        self.front_right.backward()
        self.front_left.forward()

        self.rear_right.forward()
        self.rear_left.forward()

    def backward_right(self):
        self.front_right.backward(1)
        self.front_left.forward(1)

        self.rear_right.forward(1)
        self.rear_left.forward(0.2)

    def backward_left(self):
        self.front_right.backward(1)
        self.front_left.forward(1)

        self.rear_right.forward(0.2)
        self.rear_left.forward(1)

    def forward_left(self):
        self.front_right.forward()
        self.front_left.backward(0.2)

        self.rear_right.backward(1)
        self.rear_left.backward(1)

    def forward_right(self):
        self.front_right.forward(0.2)
        self.front_left.backward(1)

        self.rear_right.backward(1)
        self.rear_left.backward(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.front_right.stop()
        self.front_left.stop()

        self.rear_right.stop()
        self.rear_left.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.cleanup()

    commands = {
        "f": "forward",
        "b": "backward",
        "s": "stop"
    }
    try:
        car = Car()

        while True:
            command = raw_input()
            getattr(car, commands[command])()
    finally:
        try:
            GPIO.cleanup()
        except:  # ignore cleanup errors
            pass
```

(I've also mixed up some motors and pins on the board which led to some motors accepting "backwards" as "forward")

It is, of course, difficult to explain this kind of code to a 6-year old, since she still expects a printer to print something when I show her the Python's `print()` command, but, how would you change this code to make it more understandable for a kid?

I would also appreciate any points about the code organization and quality since the next step would be to control the car "via Bluetooth".

Comment: Have you considered using WASD controls as many PC games do? That would seem more natural than F, B and S in my opinion. Kudos for the project though, that sounds like a great way to teach a child to build something!

Comment: @Phrancis thanks! wasd would be better..or may be even arrow up, down, left, right - a bit more straightforward for a kid..

Comment: You could make both, I do agree arrows would be simpler for a kid. Maybe space bar for brakes. Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't you just swap the pin numbers in the program rather than changing the actual wiring and still end up with forward and backward actually going in the right direction?

Comment: @IllusiveBrian ah, sounds right, should work, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I know it would probably be a much more of an effort, but you could consider trying to make the program for the car using [Google Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/). Kids love colors and puzzles and this is awesome tool for children, and plus it compiles directly to Python. To dig deeper into Blockly, check out this: https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/overview

Comment: Would it be possible to implement state machine for this? It sounds really like you need finite state machine for all these movements and extract truth table out of the states. I will find it more intuitive.

Comment: Very ambitious project to teach a 6 year old to code but I fully agree python is the language to start with and applaud you for giving it a try

Comment: Thinking of how you want to add Bluetooth to it at some point, what rpi do you have because that would be a lot easier with a zero w or 3B because they have built in WiFi and Bluetooth

Comment: @13ros27 yeah, we have both - we've used 3 for this one..working on a bluetooth at the moment..thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The implementation of `forward` is horrible. The only correct way of expressing it is to make all four motors go forward. As an analogy, how would you react if your keyboard manufacturer told you "oh sorry, we made a mistake, you have to type every second letter in uppercase to get a lowercase word"? That would be non-intuitive.

The API you provide must be as clean and simple as possible. You don't want your daughter to learn that "programmers make mistakes and are lazy about fixing them, so we have to live with that".

In which ways is your daughter supposed to change the current program? You should probably add some example code for waiting some time, to allow for composed commands like "forward, wait 1s, right, 1s, backward".

Your code seems to crash with an exception when an unexpected key is pressed. That's unacceptable for a robot, since it might harm people or pets when running uncontrolled (see Asimov's laws).

Using `raw_input` looks as if the user has to press the Enter key to confirm each action. That's too much of a burden. Controlling the car must be simple and immediate, to prevent accidents. How would you feel if your grown-up street car would ask you for confirmation for each step on the gas or brake?

Comment: Wow, super good points. It was our start and we are absolutely ready to learn from our mistakes. About the composed commands - nice idea, I was thinking to create a path/road for her to try to get through by making a combination of actions. Interesting take about safety as well. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not sure a toy car needs to implement Asimov's laws.

Comment: @jwg I'm definitely blaming you when super intelligent toy cars enslave us all.

Comment: Asimov's Laws while very clever are not entirely relevant to actual day to day life (and coding) but other than that, great points

Answer (score 27):

- From my experience, kids understand DRY without explanation, and in fact they are very bored by the repetition.
- > which led to some motors accepting "backwards" as "forward"

  This is I am afraid a dire mistake. Fix it as soon as you can, because it may ruin kid's intuition.Even I can't grok why `forward` method is so asymmetric.
- Do not rely on magic numbers and default argument values. Defaults are really hard to grasp.

All that said, I believe the question is better suited for [CSE](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com) exchange.

Comment: or CodeReview ?

Comment: [Children **love** repetition](https://www.babble.com/toddler/how-to-read-out-loud-toddlers/). It's the number one tool for education. The Teletubbies would almost constantly repeat the same process (taking a certain action) **four** times, one for each Teletubby. Dora the Explorer keeps repeating the same plan over and over again during an episode. As a kid, I rewatched my favorite movies over and over again, and never once got bored rewatching it (and I paid attention, it wasn't just background noise). I _still_ know most of The Nightmare Before Christmas' script by heart ;)

Comment: @Flater some do, some don't. I, for one, was extremely quickly bored by anything even remotely repetitious.

Comment: Two year olds like the core Teletubbies audience are a lot more into repetition than six year olds like the OP's daughter.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a Pi+python control program so I had a quick look at what I did.
Interestingly I noticed that I seem to have had the same problem with forwards and backwards. I found this comment:

```
# Forwards and backwards are the same for left and right
# The trick is to reverse the motor connections for one  side :-)
```

Thus I solved it by swapping the connections for both motors on one side.
I could tell you where the code it but it is on a website which has my product and I don't want to advertise. It uses a different motor controller but the principle is the same. Here is the core code:

```
# Main program

# Get the curses screen
screen = curses.initscr()

..... <omitted code to set up the I/O>

# Tell user what to expect
# in curses print does not work anymore. use addstr
screen.addstr("<prouduct name> example program for Python\n")
screen.addstr("Use numeric keypad keys control\n")
screen.addstr("Left  Both  Right\n")
screen.addstr("     Forward     \n")
screen.addstr("  7     8     9  \n")
screen.addstr("                 \n")
screen.addstr("  4    Stop   6  \n")
screen.addstr("                 \n")
screen.addstr("  1     2     3  \n")
screen.addstr("     Reverse     \n")
screen.addstr("Left  Both  Right\n")
screen.addstr("Don't forget to set numlock on!!!!\n")
screen.addstr("Use Q or q to quit\n")
screen.addstr("\n")


run = 1
while run==1 :
  key = screen.getch() # Key?
  if key==ord('q') :
    run = 0 # stop running

  if key==ord('1') : 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,BACKW) # Left backwards 

  if key==ord('2') : 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,BACKW)  # Left backwards 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,BACKW) # Right backwards 

  if key==ord('3') : 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,BACKW) # Right backwards 

  if key==ord('4') :
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,STOP) # Left stop 

  if key==ord('5') : 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,STOP)  # Left stop 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,STOP) # Right stop 

  if key==ord('6') :
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,STOP) # Right stop 

  if key==ord('7') :
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,FORWD) # Left forwards 

  if key==ord('8') :
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,LEFT,FORWD)  # Left forwards 
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,FORWD) # Right forwards 

  if key==ord('9') :
     gb.move_brushed(BOARD,RIGHT,FORWD) # Right forwards 

# on exist stop everything
gb.emerg_stop()
# Set terminal behaviour normal again
curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Ah, nice one. I've stumbled upon `curses` for reading the user inputs - I think I should finally give it a try for this problem. And thanks for the tip to swap the connections.

Answer (score 3):

On a different note, in order to not have to press enter after every command you could add the following modification to the main part of the code to use pygame although this would make it less understandable so I would definitely keep both versions.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.cleanup()

    try:
        car = Car()
        import pygame

        while True:
            events = pygame.event.get()
            for event in events:
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        car.forward()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        car.forward_left()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        car.forward_right()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        car.backward()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        car.stop()
    finally:
        try:
            GPIO.cleanup()
        except:  # ignore cleanup errors
            pass
```

Where wasd or arrow keys controls its movement and space stops it.

With thanks to @Haz on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044229/how-to-get-keyboard-input-in-pygame

Comment: Using `pygame` is such a nice idea - out-of-the-box thinking, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think the advice from `import this` will help you here, especially "Explicit is better than implicit", "Simple is better than complex", "Flat is better than nested" and "Readability counts." In particular, I would note that you are creating a `Car` class which can only be used as a singleton. But Python modules are already perfectly valid singleton classes, so you can eliminate a level of abstraction and nesting by implementing everything directly at the module level.

I would also agree with others that you must fix the forward/backward problems, and it's a good idea to always specify the motor speed rather than relying on defaults. I like your event stack approach, but I would reference functions directly (not by name) and I would add an extra step to make it easier to see what's happening.

This gives simpler code, like this:

```
from RPi import GPIO
from gpiozero import Motor, OutputDevice

# setup GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
OutputDevice(5).on()
OutputDevice(17).on()
OutputDevice(25).on()
OutputDevice(12).on()

# setup motor references (with correct forward/backward settings)
front_right = Motor(forward=24, backward=27)
front_left = Motor(forward=22, backward=6)
rear_right = Motor(forward=18, backward=13)
rear_left = Motor(forward=16, backward=23)

# define available commands
def forward(self):
    front_right.forward(1)
    front_left.forward(1)
    rear_right.forward(1)
    rear_left.forward(1)

def backward(self):
    front_right.backward(1)
    front_left.backward(1)
    rear_right.backward(1)
    rear_left.backward(1)

def backward_right(self):
    front_right.backward(1)
    front_left.backward(1)
    rear_right.backward(1)
    rear_left.backward(0.2)

def backward_left(self):
    front_right.backward(1)
    front_left.backward(1)
    rear_right.backward(0.2)
    rear_left.backward(1)

def forward_left(self):
    front_right.forward(1)
    front_left.forward(0.2)
    rear_right.forward(1)
    rear_left.forward(1)

def forward_right(self):
    front_right.forward(0.2)
    front_left.forward(1)
    rear_right.forward(1)
    rear_left.forward(1)

def stop(self):
    front_right.stop()
    front_left.stop()
    rear_right.stop()
    rear_left.stop()

commands = {
    "f": forward,
    "b": backward,
    "s": stop
}

try:
    while True:
        # better to use another library that can use arrow keys and maybe spacebar for stop
        command = raw_input() 
        func = commands[command]
        func()
finally:
    try:
        GPIO.cleanup()
    except:  # ignore cleanup errors
        pass
```

If you want a DRYer approach, you could do this (at the cost of more abstraction):

```
from RPi import GPIO
from gpiozero import Motor, OutputDevice

# setup GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
OutputDevice(5).on()
OutputDevice(17).on()
OutputDevice(25).on()
OutputDevice(12).on()

# setup motor references (with correct forward/backward settings)
motors = dict(
    front_right=Motor(forward=24, backward=27),
    front_left=Motor(forward=22, backward=6),
    rear_right=Motor(forward=18, backward=13),
    rear_left=Motor(forward=16, backward=23)
)

# define available commands (dicts of speeds for each motor)
commands = {
    "f": dict(front_right=1, front_left=1, rear_right=1, rear_left=1),
    "b": dict(front_right=-1, front_left=-1, rear_right=-1, rear_left=-1),
    "s": dict(front_right=0, front_left=0, rear_right=0, rear_left=0),
}

def set_motor_speed(motor, speed):
    if speed < 0:
        motor.backward(-speed)
    elif speed == 0:
        motor.stop()
    else:
        motor.forward(speed)

def run_command(command):
    settings=commands[command]
    for motor_name, speed in settings.items():
        set_motor_speed(motors[motor_name], speed)

try:
    while True:
        # better to use another library that can use arrow keys and maybe spacebar for stop
        command = raw_input() 
        run_command(command)
finally:
    try:
        GPIO.cleanup()
    except:  # ignore cleanup errors
        pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by `import this`

Comment: @13ros27, try it! Or see Python PEP 20: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: PEP20 is just my life manifesto! I really like the additional abstractions you’ve presented. Thank you, Matthias.

Comment: Oh yeah, cool, I never knew that

Comment: @alexce, glad to help! But I think most six-year-olds will have trouble with dicts of dicts and negative-negative numbers (might help to use `abs(speed)` instead of `-speed`). Mine certainly isn't ready for those! But at least the 'API' should be pretty easy to use.

Comment: I think the class makes it nicer although harder for newbie programmers (especially 6 year olds) to read however I think the lack of checking it is run from main is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.front_right = Motor(forward=24, backward=27)
        self.front_left = Motor(forward=22, backward=6)

        self.rear_right = Motor(forward=18, backward=13)
        self.rear_left = Motor(forward=16, backward=23)
```

This modification to the `__init__` method should mean that it doesn't matter that you muddled the pins up because I just reversed the ones which are muddled up. NOTE: It still needs the bit of code to switch them on.
Also, it may be beneficial if this is to try and help someone to learn coding to add comments to detail what everything does.